# creating an alarm for sagemaker endpoint in cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create an alarm for a sagemaker endpoint using cloudformation. My endpoint has two variants. My cloud formation file looks similar to below:

```
MySagemakerAlarmCPUUtilization:
  Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm'
  Properties:
    AlarmName: MySagemakerAlarmCPUUtilization
    AlarmDescription: Monitor the CPU levels of the endpoint
    MetricName: CPUUtilization
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
    Dimension:
      - Name: EndpointName
        Value: my-endpoint
      - Name: VariantName
        Value: variant1
    Namespace: AWS/SageMaker/Endpoints
    EvaluationPeriods: 1
    Period: 600
    Statistic: Average
    Threshold: 50
```

I am having an issue though with the `dimension` part. I get an invalid property error here. Does anyone know the correct syntax to look at a particular variant of an endpoint in cloud formation?

Answer (score 0):

Realised I just had a typo in this. It should read `Dimensions`. So:

```
Dimensions:
  - Name: EndpointName
    Value: my-endpoint
  - Name: VariantName
    Value: variant1
```

But the code is right if anyone else wanted to use it